# jquery match prefix window.location.pathname

Tags: jquery

I have my menu here:

```
<ul>
    <li class="step-1"><a href="/why-build">Why Build</a></li>
    <li class="step-2"><a href="/land">Land</a></li>
    <li class="step-3"><a href="/builders">Builders</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to add class "selected" to menu item when I am on that page (i.e /why-build), or its sub pages(i.e /why-build/page1, or /why-build/page2 etc). The first li would be

```
<li class="step-1 selected"><a href="/why-build">Why Build</a></li>
```

So basically to all urls match pattern /why-build/*. How can I check with window.location.pathname? Sorry I am not good at regex. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.filter()` to match the beginning of the pathname against `href`.

```
$("li").removeClass("selected");
$("li > a").filter(function() {
    return window.location.pathname.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) == 0;
}).parent().addClass("selected");
```

This assumes you don't do something silly like having folders `/why-build` and `/why-build2`. I could make it safer, searching for the `/` explicitly in the pathname and then comparing substrings, or using a regular expression. If you need that, consider it a learning exercise.

Comment: But don't we need to do the opposite? window.location.pathname=/why-build/page2 when we are on page /why-build/page2. Then /why-build doesn't not match a[href^='/why-build/page2'], 'selected' class could not added.

Answer (score 0):

Use following to match

**HTML** :

```
<ul>
    <li class="step-1"><a href="/why-build">Why Build</a></li>
    <li class="step-1"><a href="/why-build/page1">Why Build</a></li>
    <li class="step-2"><a href="/land">Land</a></li>
    <li class="step-3"><a href="/builders">Builders</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Script** :

```
$("li").removeClass("selected");
$("a[href*='why-build']").parent('li').addClass("selected");
```

Following are the symbol notation for attributes selector:

```
= is exactly equal
!= is not equal
^= is starts with
$= is ends with
*= is contains
```

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/MbGE2/

For more details refer :  [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)